# An alternate to foldLeft that starts from second element

Tags: scala, fold

I have a `List` defined as:

```
val l = List("1", "2", "3")
```

I want to convert it to the string

```
"1:2:3"
```

One way is the following:

```
l.foldLeft("")((x, y) => x + (if (x == "") "" else ":") +y)
```

Is there a more elegant method?

[EDIT: further explanation]

Easy Angel's answer works when the elements of `l` have a 'meaningful' `toString` method.

although I have `l` as `List[String]`, `l` can be a list of a custom type which does not override the `toString` method, say, as in:

```
class my(i:Int) {
  val x = i
}
```

I have also a method

```
def getMy(m:my) = "Hello "+m.x
```

So I would like the output of `getMy` to be used instead of the output of the default `toString` method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `mkString` method of `List`:

```
l mkString ":"
```

More info can be found in scaladoc:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc/scala/collection/Iterable.html#mkString:String

---

As alternative you can use `reduceLeft` for example:

```
l.reduceLeft(_ + ":" + _)
```

---

As an answer to your second question: Just combine it with `map`:

```
l map getMy mkString ":"
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution using `map`. For clarity, I'd write it as `(l map getMy) mkString ":"`. I feel stupid for not figuring it out myself.

Comment: @Jus12: Isn't it elegant and concise. Oh... I love Scala :)

Comment: Yes, very elegant, though the other answers are also good. For instance, they can be used to do more generic stuff apart form converting to string. BTW, yes, Scala is awesome!

Comment: And of course, I completely overlooked the nice solution using `reduceLeft`.

Answer (score 2):

another way to do this with just foldLeft:

```
l.tail.foldLeft(l.head)( (x, y) => x+":"+y )
```

Answer (score 1):

The other suggestions are better, but when you want to keep foldLeft, you could use Options:

```
List("1","2","3").foldLeft(None:Option[String])((o,n)=> o.map(_+":"+n).orElse(Some(n))).get
//res2: String = 1:2:3
```